# Why $variable++ not working properly in Lavarel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-components

I just encounter a situation where I need to display index for each row of table, For this I created a variable ($number) in blade view file and set it to 0. For row of my table I created a component and pass my data to it, incrementing index ($number) for each row. But actually it is incrementing twice.

My blade :

```html
@if($staff_profile->passport_expiry!=null&&$staff_profile->passport_expiry<$exp_date)
    <x-staf_expiry_row :id=" $staff_profile->id" :name="$staff_profile->name" type="Passport" :date="$staff_profile->passport_expiry" :number="$number++"/>
@endif
```

and the result is:

[image: before]

But it works fine after a simple change :

```html
@if($staff_profile->passport_expiry!=null&&$staff_profile->passport_expiry<$exp_date)
    <x-staf_expiry_row :id=" $staff_profile->id" :name="$staff_profile->name" type="Passport" :date="$staff_profile->passport_expiry" :number="$number++"/>
    @php($number++)
@endif
```

[image: after]

Why $number++ increment twice and what's the proper way of doing it?

Thanks for your time!

---

**EDIT:**
my table body in blade:

```html
<tbody>
     @foreach($staff_profiles as $key => $staff_profile)
        @if ($staff_profile->passport_expiry != null && $staff_profile->passport_expiry < $exp_date)
            <x-staf_expiry_row :id=" $staff_profile->id" :name="$staff_profile->name" type="Passport" :date="$staff_profile->passport_expiry" :number="$number++"/>                       
        @endif
        @if ($staff_profile->visa_expiry != null && $staff_profile->visa_expiry < $exp_date)
            <x-staf_expiry_row :id=" $staff_profile->id" :name="$staff_profile->name" type="Visa" :date="$staff_profile->visa_expiry" :number="$number++"/>                       
        @endif
        @if ($staff_profile->emirates_id_expiry != null && $staff_profile->emirates_id_expiry < $exp_date)
            <x-staf_expiry_row :id=" $staff_profile->id" :name="$staff_profile->name" type="Emirates Id Expiry" :date="$staff_profile->emirates_id_expiry" :number="$number++"/>                       
        @endif
        @if ($staff_profile->labor_card_expiry != null && $staff_profile->labor_card_expiry < $exp_date)
            <x-staf_expiry_row :id=" $staff_profile->id" :name="$staff_profile->name" type="Labor Card Expiry" :date="$staff_profile->labor_card_expiry" :number="$number++"/>                       
        @endif
        @if ($staff_profile->contract_expiry != null && $staff_profile->contract_expiry < $exp_date)
            <x-staf_expiry_row :id=" $staff_profile->id" :name="$staff_profile->name" type="Contract Expiry" :date="$staff_profile->contract_expiry" :number="$number++"/>                       
        @endif
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable) variable from `@foreach`, so, let's say you have a `@foreach`, you should have this blade:

```html
@foreach ($staff_profiles as $staff_profile)
    @if($staff_profile->passport_expiry != null && $staff_profile->passport_expiry < $exp_date)
       <x-staf_expiry_row :id="$staff_profile->id" :name="$staff_profile->name" type="Passport" :date="$staff_profile->passport_expiry" :number="$loop->index"/>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: actually I cant, as in for each i have 6 if condition, which will generate new row , and index has to be different. My main concern was why blade is incrementing twice.
thanks BTW for your help :)

Comment: @UsamaJalal could you share the whole file then?

Comment: edited, have a look

Comment: @UsamaJalal I saw the update, so my question would be, what are you using `$number` for? Why do you need to increment it? Depending on your answer, I could say, you may pass the property name and the `$loop->index` so you end up having `$array[$loop->index] = ['Passport' => xxxx. 'Visa' => xxxx];` but I am not sure how you are using `$number` and what for